# Input/output error after entering "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: server, updates

I'm trying to update my server. I input:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And it spits back:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Input/output error
```

Rebooting the server allows me to enter the update and upgrade command normally. But if I start the server and let it run on its own for a few days, it behaves this way until I reboot it again.

Comment: Have you run a filesystem check with fsck or checked the disk with smartctl from the smartmontools package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/q/904121/301745)